# Mean square consistent but not asymptotically unbiased?

Tags: statistics

I stumbled over this paper [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/9/5/544/htm) where asymptotical unbiasedness and mean square conistence are shown for a statistic. I know that asymptotical unbiasedness plus vanishing variance induce mean square consistency, but can you provide an example for an asymptotically biased estimator that is mean square consistent?

Answer (score 2):

An estimator that is mean-square consistent is automatically asymptotically unbiased, so the situation you are describing is impossible. Indeed, if $U_n$ is mean square consistent as an estimator for parameter $\theta$, this means
$
E[(U_n-\theta)^2]\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Use the inequality $E(X^2)\ge [E(X)]^2$ to see that
$$[E(U_n-\theta)]^2\le E[(U_n-\theta)^2]$$ which implies $E(U_n)\to\theta$.